# PHP: Escaping single quotes in javascript echoed by php?

Tags: php

I have an echo in my php page which has a javascript in it.

it looks like this:

```
echo '<ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('home.html')" tappable>';
```

I need to escape the single quotes on `fn.load('home.html')`

so i did:

```
 echo '<ons-list-item onclick="fn.load(/'home.html'/)" tappable>';
```

But that doesn't really work..

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using double quotes around "home.html".

Or you need to escape ", so it won't be interpreted as end of string. Use \ to escape the quotes as you said.

Comment: with double quotes, my javascript stops working. so i need to use single quotes.

Comment: OK try using the backslash before to escape the quote using a backslash.
Like thus 
'hello\'s'